# No auth id assigned for intent=authorize

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I think the ReSt authorization API is broken, I don't get back the ID for the auth object when doing POST /payment with intent=authorize.

Even calling GET /v1/payments/payment/{id} I don't get an auth id.

Here's the http log: http://pastebin.com/e1bEjfBF

As you can see I get "related_resources":[{"authorization":{"create_time"... but there is no id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pastbin sample shows the lookup of a payment resource that has not been approved yet.

Generally, for a PayPal Payment in Rest, you will have to:

1. Create a PayPal payment (POST payment request to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment)
2. Redirect the buyer to the returned Approval_URL (usually something like https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=)
3. Upon return of the buyer to the return_url you specified in step 1, execute the payment (POST the PayerID to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-xxxx/execute/)

When you now lookup the Pay-Key, you should see the state of the Pay-Key as "approved", included buyer details, an Authorization TXN-ID and authorization state of "Authorized".

The next step would be to call the appropriate HATEOAS links to capture, void or reauthorize the authorization.

I've uploaded a sample flow to http://pastebin.com/JWG8Gzuv

You can also refer to the developer documentation located under https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/capture-payment/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, however in step 3 (the payment is now approved) I don't see an authorisation id when doing a GET /v1/payments/payment/PAY-XXXX, nor is the state set to approved (it still says state: created), even though it clearly is, as I can see the payer information. Please see http://pastebin.com/CiRXjhDq